# How to make play an animation from current frame until N seconds en Rive

Tags: rive

I have an animation and an input, I want to play my animation **N seconds** from current frame every time  my input change his value

I was using `scrub` function but that only jumps between frames, that help to has controll over the animation but it seem a little laggy